# Urn problem and combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

You have $5$ red and $4$ black balls. How many ways there are to distribute all to $3$ different bottles?

If I had $9$ red balls, then it would be $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ = $\binom{3+9-1}{9}$, but I have no idea how to solve it when I have different colours...

Example: 1 Red, 1 Black and 2 Bottle (b_x for bottle)

If you have 1 Red ball  1 Black ball and 2 Bottles then you  have four options:

first option: In Bottle 1 : Red and Black and there no one in Bottle 2.

second option: In Bottle 1 : Red and there is Black in Bottle 2.

third option: In Bottle 1 : Black and there is Red in Bottle 2.

fourth option:  In Bottle 1 : empty  and there is Red and Black in Bottle 2.

Comment: Some clarification may be helpful. Does order matter?  Just looking at the red balls in the three bottles...would you distinguish between {0, 2, 3} and {3, 0, 2}? Have you tried working with smaller numbers (where you can comfortably list all the possibilities)?

Comment: i edited it  to my question

Comment: I can't quite understand the edit...does the order matter?  Suppose there is 1 red ball and one black ball.  What's the answer then?  If order does not matter the answer is 2 ("both balls in one bottle", "the two balls are in different bottles").  If the order does matter it is 9 (red ball has 3 choices, black ball has 3 choices and choices are independent).)

Comment: yes the order does matter so if you u have 1 red ball and one black ball and 3 bottles -> total 9 combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You know how to calculate the number of ways to distribute $5$ red balls amongst the $3$ bottles, and you know how to calculate the number of ways to distribute $4$ black balls amongst the $3$ bottles. Say there are $r$ ways to do the first and $b$ ways to do the second. The two distributions can be combined arbitrarily: each of the $r$ possible distribution of red balls can occur with any of the $b$ possible distributions of black balls. So how many different possibilities are there altogether?

Comment: Very good answer... this is really enlightening.

Comment: 3^9 would be the answer?

Comment: @Row.: That would be the answer if the balls were individually identifiable – if they were numbered, for instance. Here, though, the only thing that distinguishes them is color: the $5$ red balls are interchangeable, and so are the $4$ black balls. We count RRRBB, RB, RB as only one arrangement, no matter which of the red balls are in which box. Start by finding the numbers $r$ and $b$ that I mentioned in my answer; your question shows that you know the formula for doing so.

Comment: basically thats the idea :$\binom{3+5-1}{5} *\binom{3+4-1}{4} $

Comment: @Row.: Yes, that’s right.